# how to grep in the output of ls -a

Tags: grep, ls, timestamps

I'd like to `grep` the output of `ls` and pipe it into `less` so I can scroll through the output.

This doesn't work, but ideally, I'd be able to type this:

```
ls -alh | grep "file" | less
```

Any suggestion how to do this? My over-all goal is to view the modification dates of all files in the current directory which contain "file" in their filenames. I have read into `stat` but this seems too verbose for my purposes.

Comment: Why doesn't this work? That will correctly pipe the output of `ls -alh | grep "file" ` to `less`. Are you expecting `less` to open `file`?

Comment: It may be a speed issue actually. I didn't create a minimal test case so am running this on a folder with 20k files in it (and through ssh if that makes a difference). I didn't let it work for more than a few minutes...

Comment: _Minutes_? That's surprising. But at least try `ls -alh *file* | less` first, there's no need for `grep` here.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I didn't realize that usage of `ls` was valid

Comment: @terdon That should probably be `ls -alhd -- *file*` to avoid listing the contents of directories and to protect from files whose name start with a dash.

Comment: @kevinkayaks what Kusalananda said. He's quite right.

Comment: Thank Stéphane, it was he who reminded me about the `--` (as usual) :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming `stat` being "too verbose" means the command outputs a lot of other information too, which it does by default if you don't request specific bits of info from it.

With GNU `stat`:

```
stat --printf '%y\t%n\n' -- *file*
```

That would output only the modification timestamp in human-readable format followed by a tab and the filename.  This will be done on all filenames that contains the substring `file`.   Set the `dotglob` shell option in `bash`, with `shopt -s dotglob`, to also allow hidden filenames to be included.

Use `%Y` in place of `%y` to get the modification timestamps in seconds since Epoch instead.

On BSD systems, use

```
stat -f '%Sm%t%N' -- *file*
```

instead (does the same thing).  Change `%Sm` to `%Fm` to get seconds since the Epoch.

See the manual for `stat` (`man 1 stat`) on you system for further information.

Comment: thanks @Kusalanda, this works great. I modified with `%w` for creation timestamp